# IE9: Force IE9 browser mode and document mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, my webpage is displaying as `Browser Mode: IE9 Compat View` and `Document Mode: IE standards`, which is breaking all my `canvas`es.

I have made sure to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first line.

How can I force "normal" IE9 mode on IE9?

Comment: Have you checked your html to ensure that it is well formed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the "edge" mode.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

From the linked MSDN page:

> Edge mode tells Windows Internet Explorer to display content in the
>   highest mode available, which actually breaks the “lock-in” paradigm.
>   With Internet Explorer 8, this is equivalent to IE8 mode. If a
>   (hypothetical) future release of Internet Explorer supported a higher
>   compatibility mode, pages set to Edge mode would appear in the highest
>   mode supported by that version; however, those same pages would still
>   appear in IE8 mode when viewed with Internet Explorer 8.

However, "edge" mode is not encouraged in production use:

It is recommended that Web developers restrict their use of Edge mode to test pages and other non-production uses because of the possible unexpected results of rendering page content in future versions of Windows Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

The following line, taken from HTML5 boilerplate, did the job:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```