# Force Internet Explorer 10 Document Mode

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer

Basically I have been going through a problem and would like to enforce my browser to be used under Browser Mode: IE 10 Compatable View and Document Mode: Quirks.

As in IE 10 Document Mode is IE 5 Quirks and only Quirks but, I am unable to enforce it by using document mode and meta-tag too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
```

This is what I have been trying but no luck.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do here.... you say you *want* quirks mode???? Why on earth would you want that?

Comment: Please go through this post, might be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838605/force-browser-and-document-mode-to-ie9-in-ie10

Comment: Basically the application is too old on which I am working and can't change to much code to setup the UI but i have testing it by changing the browser mode and document mode and it's seems perfect on IE Compatibility View with Quirks

Comment: I suggest using standards mode, and having `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` in your CSS. This will fix most layout issues and avoid having to use quirks mode.

Comment: `IE=EDGE` means "Use IE10 Standards mode". You want `IE=EmulateIE7` which means "Use Compatibility view, and use Quirks mode if the document isn't in standards mode."

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, if the browser it IE10 the rendering machine will be changed to latest one.

```
!--  Force IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine -->  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

[`chrome=1`](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Making-Your-Pages-Work-With-Google-Chrome-Frame) means IE should use the [Chrome rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_Frame) if installed

I think changing document type **`Quirks`** seems a bad idea, however if you need then you may have to remove the **`!DOCTYPE`**.

> If none of these rules apply, the  declaration determines
>   whether the webpage renders in a standards mode, Almost Standards
>   mode, or quirks mode.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have chrome engine installed on my machine but in chrome it's showing ui in different manner and in IE 10 some different way

Comment: <!DOCTYPE> changed my document mode to IE 7 Standards

Comment: @WasifKirmani on removing <!DOCTYPE> changed your mode to IE7 right?

Comment: @WasifKirmani Seems weird.  Remove you the existing `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>` and make it completely like `!DOCTYPE`