# Is there anyway to force Browser mode to be IE 10 Compatibility View

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

My Web App has some problem on IE10 if not use compatibility view.

I do some research and found a solution that say i have to use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

So i try to use it but the problem was still remain.

Document mode was change to IE7 as I wish but Browser mode was not change to Compatibility view.

Is there anyway to force IE10 to use

```
Browser Mode: IE10 Compatibility View
```

on my web app?

or Is there any javascript that can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look: http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm

Comment: Thank you.
but I already try that with no luck.
It's Change just document mode to IE5 quirk but not browser mode to compat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Browser and Document Mode to ie9 in ie10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838605/force-browser-and-document-mode-to-ie9-in-ie10)

Answer (score 1):

Now i just don't need to force browser compatibility view anymore.
I just found out that my web app problem was cause by .net framework browser definition issue.

More information on this blog:
http://www.ampedupdesigns.com/blog/show?bid=54