# Script to turn off the browser mode : compact view

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have converted my Website in HTML5 by adding `<!doctype html>` on the top of the page.
By default, compatibility view in my IE browsers (IE8,IE9,IE10) is ON which I can make it OFF manually only. When I make it off, my application display proper. I want to make it OFF automatically **by the script (any HTML tag or JS)**. Is it possible?

I have already searched this on SO and found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800290/ie9-force-ie9-browser-mode-and-document-mode) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761037/force-ie9-to-use-browser-mode-not-compatibility-mode). But it is providing a solution to add  tag which is not my solution.

`Current scenario: Browser mode : IE9 compact view, document mode : IE9 standard`
`Expected scenario: Browser mode : IE9 , document mode : IE9 standard`

Answer (score 0):

**ursitesion said:**

> I have already searched this on SO and found one post and link. But it is providing a solution to add tag which is not my solution.

Did that solution work for you, and if it did, why was it not the solution you wanted?

This will help me better answer the question.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">  I am expecting Browser Mod: IE 9 but getting Browser Mod: Compact View, 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>